# How to start drillbit locally in distributed mode?

Tags: apache-drill

I downloaded Apache Drill v1.8, edited the `conf/drill-override.conf` to have the following changes:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "10.178.23.140:2181,10.178.23.140:2182,10.178.23.140:2183,10.178.23.140:2184"
}
```

..zookeeper cluster is effectively consisted of 4 Zookeeper instances started on the same, one machine, I'm trying to start Drill on. (i.e. I'm only using one machine for Apache Drill and Zookeeper's cluster, the machine's IP is **10.178.23.140**)

So I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failure during initial startup of Drillbit.
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:295)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:271)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:267)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Drillbit is disallowed to bind to loopback address in distributed mode.
    at org.apache.drill.exec.service.ServiceEngine.checkLoopbackAddress(ServiceEngine.java:186)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.service.ServiceEngine.start(ServiceEngine.java:146)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:119)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:291)
    ... 2 more
```

Why does drillbit complain about being bound to a loopback address ?!

1. I didn't configure an IP for drillbit to bind to !
2. And since I'm starting drillbit process on my machine, what other IP that my machine would it be try to bind to ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that my **/etc/hosts** file had this entry

```
127.0.1.1   mgelbana-machine
```

This made my hostname resolvable to a loopback address. To resolve this, you can do either of the following

- Removing this line resolved my problem.
- Having my hostname resolved to a non-loopback IP address.

[Source](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/service/ServiceEngine.java#L195)

```
private void checkLoopbackAddress(String address) throws DrillbitStartupException, UnknownHostException {
  if (isDistributedMode && InetAddress.getByName(address).isLoopbackAddress()) {
    throw new DrillbitStartupException("Drillbit is disallowed to bind to loopback address in distributed mode.");
  }
}
```

The reason why Drill refuses to startup while bound to a loopback address, is to [differentiate between Drill nodes registered in Zookeeper.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4523)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the following [Drill system option](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/#system-options), which was introduced in Drill 1.14:

```
drill.exec.allow_loopback_address_binding: true
```

Specify this option in the `/conf/drill-override.conf` file.