# Apache drill address loopback exception in apache drill

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I have a similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506221/how-to-start-drillbit-locally-in-distributed-mode)
I 'm looking to start zookeeper with drill in the same local cluser (localhost)

but i'm having always a loopback adress problem, and if I delete the entry in my ect/hosts, another exception saying inet adress could not be resolved is thrown.

what to do to start both in the same machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, by changing the adresse of the local machine (not localhost) to the internet adresse or public IP adresse (you should be connected to the internet) start again drillbit it will run successfully.
once it is running you can change it back to the loopback adresse 127.0.0.1 so you can work without the internet connection.

Comment: @here for security reasons our server doesn't have a public ip.  Is there still a solution to the problem, thanks!